# SQL calculate bounce rate

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL table (Postgres):

```
+-----------+------------+-------+
| SessionID |  Received  | Event |
+-----------+------------+-------+
|         1 | 1595207019 | visit |
|         1 | 1595207020 | play  |
|         2 | 1595207040 | visit |
|         1 | 1595207050 | click |
+-----------+------------+-------+
```

I want to calculate bounce rate where **bounce** is defined as visit event not followed by any other event with the same session id.

Comment: What if there are multiple visits in a session?  What if a session has no visits?

Comment: It is not possible to have multiple `"visit" events in a session, visit is essentially the session creation event. For same reason a session can't exist without a "visit" event. Actually in my application the event is even called "session_start", I wanted to simplify it for this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly query for the number of "bounces" like this:

```sql
select count(*)
from t as t1
where t1.event = 'visit'
  and not exists (select * from t as t2 where t1.received < t2.received and t1.sessionid = t2.sessionid)
```

Not sure what is the denominator of the "bounce rate" specifically? Bounces per session? # bounces / # events?

Comment: denominator should be total number of sessions. So bounce rate determines the percent of sessions which have only visit event and no other event (user landed on page, thus a session was created, but didn't do anything else).

Comment: @StefanD . . . I fail to see how this calculates a "rate" and hence don't think it answers the question that you asked.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are correct, it doesn't fully answer the question but reveals the critical piece. The full solution could be: SELECT( select 100.0*count(*)
from t as t1
where t1.event = 'visit'
  and not exists (select * from t as t2 where t1.received < t2.received and t1.sessionid = t2.sessionid)) / (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT sessionid) FROM t)

Comment: @StefanD . . . Just noting that I went through the trouble of actually answering the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff not sure exactly what you're suggesting...

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think you want to summarize by `session_id` and count the types of visits.  then aggregate.  Your question is not 100% clear, but I thinK:

```
select (count(*) filter (where num_notvisits = 0) * 1.0 / count(*)) as bounce_rate
from (select session_id,
             count(*) filter (where event = 'visit') as num_visits,
             count(*) filter (where event <> 'visit') as num_notvisits
      from t
      group by session_id
     ) s
where num_visits > 0;
```

This is the ratio of the number of sessions with both a visit and a non-visit event divided by the number of sessions with a visit.

You can actually phrase the outer select more simply as:

```
select avg( (num_notvisits = 0)::int ) as bounce_rate
```